# Duplicate Image Creation USING Python ie Similar Image But Not The Original One(Decoy technique)

Tags: python, flask

builded a healthcare project on python flask framework.I need to duplicate the image or the report that is uploaded by patient and keep the original file away and only visible that duplicated report to show to any unauthorised access attackers.ie The duplicate image should be similar one but not same a little changes must have for the duplicated image. I think now u get the idea what im trying to

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to load an image file into python array, and create a new copy of that array?

If that's your demand, try using `copy()`:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("example.png")
copy_img = img.copy()
```

And you can do whatever you want with copy_img, which is independent from the original one.

Edit: 2021/6/8 22:35

If you want to copy an image located in a directory, use shutils:

```
import shutil

upload_directory = "file/upload/upload.jpg"
save_directory = "file/copy/upload_copy.jpg"
shutil.copy(upload_directory, save_directory)
```

Then you have an copied image file located in your destination directory.

Please let me know it that works.

Comment: Thanks my dear frnd for your response for helping me but,Actually i builded a healthcare project on python flask framework.I need to duplicate the image or the report that is uploaded by patient and keep the original file away and only visible that duplicated report to show to any unauthorised access attackers.ie The duplicate image should be similar one but not same a little changes must have for the duplicated image. I think now u get the idea what im trying to

Comment: I edit my reply, please take a look and see if that helps.